How to deploy mlflow's new prompt engineering UI
I'm running into issues deploying mlflow's new prompt engineering UI. I've followed these directions: https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/llms/prompt-engineering/index.html
# saved as config.yaml in directory
endpoints:
  - name: chat
    endpoint_type: llm/v1/chat
    model:
      provider: openai
      name: gpt-4
      config:
        openai_api_key: $OPENAI_API_KEY

In terminal (Mac OS):

cd /path/to/dir
export OPENAI_API_KEY=my_openai_key
mlflow deployments start-server --config-path config.yaml --port 7000
At this point I'm a bit confused, the port is accessible but all I have access to is a deployment page (see below).

If I start a new terminal and launch mlflow in a new port (5000) the UI's prompt engineering endpoint is empty (see below).


It's unclear to me if I am missing a step in the middle or how I am able to initialize access to the mlflow's new prompt engineering feature.
May or may not be related to this reported bug: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/10728

You don't mention how you start the MLflow server itself, so this is just guessing: Did you remember to set the MLFLOW_DEPLOYMENTS_TARGET environment variable, as suggested in step 2 of the documentation?
I have the following set on my machine and see the LLM model in the UI:
MLFLOW_DEPLOYMENTS_TARGET="http://127.0.0.1:7000"

If I leave the variable unset, I get the same situation you describe.
